# Android - Add A Proxy for an On-site/On-premesis only application

Tags: android, proxy, connection, certificate

I am creating an app that is going to be used on-site only, meaning it is only using it behind layers of high security.

Issue is that due to this security, the app cannot connect to the webservice which is installed on their server. We have already confirmed that the use of a private certificate is causing the issue, we continuously get `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException`... the certificate cannot be shared with us so i cannot install it directly into the application.

The devices that the app will be installed on already have VPN, but yet the connection issue persists.
A suggested work around is to use a proxy and PAC file. I was given the link to the PAC file (http://proxy-testcompany.com:3000/testproxy.pac) , but how can i use this link to help enhance the connection in order to connect to their webservice?

I use SOAP with `HttpTransportSE`

this is what i have implemented to far, but i dont think this is going to be a proper solution... if there is a solution available at all using a proxy.

`InetSocketAddress sa = InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("http://proxy-testcompany.com:3000/testproxy.pac", 3000);
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, sa);
            androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(proxy, URL, 50000);      // adding proxy`

Any suggestions would be fantastic.